# Spring JPA Derived Delete with Optional Return Type returns the deleted entity count instead of the deleted entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot application to track books. The Book entity is similar to this.

```js
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class Book implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long bookId;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String bookName;
}
```

And it has a repository, via which I can delete a book by its `bookName` attribute.

```js
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, String> {
    Optional<Book> deleteByBookName(String bookName);
}
```

And my delete method looks like this.

```js
@Transactional
public void deleteBook(String bookName) {

  Optional<Book> deletedBook = bookRepository.deleteByBookName(bookName);
  if (deletedBook.isEmpty()) {
      throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Book Not Found");
  }

}
```

However, instead of returning an `Optional<Book>` type instance, this `deleteByBookName` method returns Optional objects such as `Optional[0]`, `Optional[1]` which have the deleted book counts as values.

Due to this, `deletedBook.isEmpty()` is always true, even when 0 books are deleted.

Why this `deleteByBookName` method returns the deleted count inside Optional, instead of the deleted entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be to check the deleted count instead of deleted object.

You should refactor the method to check deleted count as shown below.

```java
@Transactional
public void deleteBook(String bookName) {

  Integer deletedBookCount = bookRepository.deleteByBookName(bookName);
  if (deletedBookCount == null || deletedBookCount == 0) {
      throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Book Not Found");
  }

}
```

Accordingly, change Repository method's signature.

```java
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, String> {
    Integer deleteByBookName(String bookName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data doesn't return deleted object after delete operation, it can returns only the deleted objects count or `void`. You can have a look also in the Spring official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.subject).

```
delete…By, remove…By - Delete query method returning either no result (void) or the delete count.
```